# After upgrading azure-iot-sdk-c from LTS_01_2021_Ref01 to LTS_07_2021_Ref01 certificate verify is flailing

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have upgraded my azure-iot-sdk-c from LTS_01_2021_Ref01 to LTS_07_2021_Ref01.
And I am observing few issues with certificate verification.
I have build the sdk with below options

```
  -Dbuild_service_client=OFF \
  -Dbuild_provisioning_service_client=OFF \
  -Ddont_use_uploadtoblob=ON \
  -Duse_prov_client=ON \
  -Duse_openssl=ON \
  -Duse_mqtt=ON \
  -Duse_default_uuid=ON \
  -Dhsm_type_custom=ON \
  -Dskip_samples=ON \
  -Duse_condition=OFF \
  -Duse_http=OFF \
  -Duse_amqp=OFF \
  -Duse_sample_trusted_cert=ON \
  -Duse_baltimore_cert=ON \
  -Dno_logging=${no_logging} \
```

And i am seeing below errors from sdk code.

Error: Time:Fri Sep 24 14:10:03 2021 File:/tmp/ci-U9cA8w3wdj/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func:send_handshake_bytes Line:734 error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Error: Time:Fri Sep 24 14:10:03 2021 File:/tmp/ci-U9cA8w3wdj/azure-iot-sdk-c/umqtt/src/mqtt_client.c Func:onOpenComplete Line:454 Error: failure opening connection to endpoint
Error: Time:Fri Sep 24 14:10:03 2021 File:/tmp/ci-U9cA8w3wdj/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/src/prov_transport_mqtt_common.c Func:mqtt_error_callback Line:139 MQTT communication error
Error: Time:Fri Sep 24 14:10:03 2021 File:/tmp/ci-U9cA8w3wdj/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/src/prov_device_ll_client.c Func:on_transport_registration_data Line:771 Failure retrieving data from the provisioning service

{"error":{"ts":1632472803823,"v":"(1009): Registration failed - Retrying. Azure registration state: PROV_DEVICE_RESULT_TRANSPORT"},"processedTs":null}

Do I need to add any flags at the time of build?

Comment: Can you add the answer and verify, as discovered in the related thread? https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/2093